# how call the itemsCart->id_product?

Tags: laravel

how can i call the id_product of the $itemsCart result line to be inserted in $ encomendas_detalhes-> id_produto?

where are the '----' is where I need help more

```
$itemsCart = cart::where('token_user', session()->get('_token') )->where('id_encomenda', 0)->get();

foreach ( $itemsCart as $items ) {
        $encomendas_detalhes = new detalhes;
        $encomendas_detalhes->id_encomenda = $encomendas->id;
        $encomendas_detalhes->id_produto = ---$itemsCart->id_produto--- ;
        $encomendas_detalhes->quantidade = 2;//$itemsCart->quantidade;
        $encomendas_detalhes->total = $total;
        $encomendas_detalhes->save();
        
        $items->id_encomenda = $id_encomenda;
        $items->save();

    }
```

Comment: It should probably be `$items->id_produto` and not `$itemsCart->id_produto`, since `$itemsCart` is a collection and not a model.

Comment: You should defnitely work on your naming. You have a singular name for a collection and a plural name for a single model, that is confusing. Also, you should work on naming stuff according to PSR standards. See https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: thanks work im dumb for momnets hahaha, but thank you, and thank for your tip, i go try improve

Comment: You can probably delete this question, otherwise it looks like it is still unsolved. Since there is not real value to the community I think the best would be to delete it instead of me giving an answer that you accept.